# Magento 2 email localhost

Tags: magento2

I am building a module. I need to modify the Magento2 email but I cannot send email in my localhost. Is there anyway to send email or to preview magento email in my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start sending emails from local machine. You could either install a mailing server on your machine like SMTP/Postfix and do the complete configuration process.

Or you can simply download this extension and configure for your email account.
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp

Configuration Process: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/configure-gmail-smtp-magento-2.html

Hope it was helpfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can send email from localhost using the SMTP Extensions. Below are the some of free extension :

> https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/
>
> How to set up SMTP Email for Magento 2 > https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-set-up-smtp-email-for-magento-2.html

> https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

Hope this helps!